# Fine-tuning SP2013 Document Library permissions

Tags: 2013, permissions, security, roles

I have the need to give access to a role for creating documents and folders in a document library and giving access to another role to create documents (but not folders)

How would I go about doing this?  The role settings control accessing to add/edit/delete documents and folders together.

Thanks